# Bad sound quality

Tags: sound, 14.04, soundcard

My sound quality is very bad in Ubuntu 14.04. How can i solved it? My laptop model is Dell Vostro 5560.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please explain your problem more. What do you mean by **bad quality**?

Answer (score 2):

## Try the [pulse audio equalizer](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/system-wide-pulseaudio-equalizer.html)

and tune it for your taste!

[image]

Comment: I would not recommend using this, because as an audio enthusiast myself, this creates way too dang much latency, thus causing crackling and distortion. You are better off buying better headphones and possibly an external amp than using this.

Comment: Works fine for me :) No idea

Comment: @mmstick I'm using the lowlatency kernel from ubuntustudio and have no latency issues with this application. If you don't like the default XFCE desktop you can always install ubuntu-desktop after installation or you could install the lowlatency kernel on top of your existing setup, just choose the lowlatency kernel from grub2 at startup after installing the lowlatency kernel `sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency`